# Remote deploying UWP from x64 machine to ARM64

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging, arm64

I have a windows x64 PC which is my development machine. I am building UWP app for ARM64 on my development machine.
In order to test and deploy the app package, I use remote debugging. When I remote deploy on the ARM64 device, I get the following error on my development machine
A dependent dll was not found.

After enabling loader snaps, I see

1f94:1f20 @ 68522921 - LdrpInitializeProcess - ERROR: Initializing the current directory to "C:\Users\remoteUserName\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\MyAppNameVS.Debug_ARM64.devMachineUserName" failed with status 0xc0000022

.
.
.
.1f94:1f20 @ 68523031 - LdrpResolveDllName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Users\remoteUserName\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\MyAppName.Debug_ARM64.devMachineUserName\A.dll
1f94:1f20 @ 68523031 - LdrpResolveDllName - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000022

the DLL in question is present physically at the location on the remote machine it's complaining about.

Remote debugger is set to have No authentication and allow any user to debug is checked

Comment: In the past I've solved some problems by running the remote debug server elevated (as Admin). That might help with installing the runtime dependencies.